# Cassandra: Fetching data but not populating cache as query does not query from the start of the partition

Tags: cassandra

I'm running Cassandra version 3.3 on a fairly beefy machine. I would like to try out the row cache so I have allocated 2 GBs of RAM for row caching and configured the target tables to cache a number of their rows.

If I run a query on a very small table (under 1 MB) twice with tracing on, on the 2nd query I see a cache hit. However, when I run a query on a large table (34 GB) I only get cache misses and see this message after every cache miss:
`Fetching data but not populating cache as query does not query from the start of the partition`

What does this mean? Do I need a bigger row cache to be able to handle a 34 GB table with 90 million keys?

Taking a look at the row cache source code on [github](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/89a645ac4ca63114d74dedc2e94a869f769b15a2/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/SinglePartitionReadCommand.java#L468), I see that `clusteringIndexFilter().isHeadFilter()` must be evaluating to false in this case. Is this a function of my partitions being too big?

My schema is:

`CREATE TABLE ap.account (
        email text PRIMARY KEY,
        added_at timestamp,
        data map< int, int >
    ) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
        AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': '100000'}
        AND comment = ''
        AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
        AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
        AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
        AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
        AND default_time_to_live = 0
        AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
        AND max_index_interval = 2048
        AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
        AND min_index_interval = 128
        AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
        AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';`

The query is simply `SELECT * FROM account WHERE email='sample@test.com'`

Comment: whats your schema and your `select` query?

Comment: I updated the question with the query